# Change Dynamic IP on Ubuntu Server 17.04

Tags: networking, server, dns, dhcp

because of keeping order as well on IP ranges mapping on local network, I would like to change my Dynamic IP address on my Ubuntu Server 17.04. I had to reinstall the Network (Routers) and got for this machine now a a new IP address as 192.168.1.37. I would like to keep it on the higher IP Range on 192.168.1.104. Is there anyone experienced with it in replacing the Dynamic IP (NOT STATIC) withtout showing up on router that this is a Static?

this is the **now** situation with a `ifconfig -a` command:

```
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.37  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2a02:121f:fdb:0:222:15ff:fe20:d220  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::222:15ff:fe20:d220  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:22:15:20:d2:20  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3237  bytes 392883 (392.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1865  bytes 1287069 (1.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 7  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 523  bytes 41761 (41.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 523  bytes 41761 (41.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

further I should define the Ports to 22, wich actually are set on 24.

Comment: If you use DHCP to setup your network and the Ubunt server revieces his IP from the router via DHCP then you need to setup your router to assign the range.  if you want to use portforwarding like sending inbound port 24 to 22 that would also be done via the router normaly.

Comment: @WooJoo: Thanks for your comment. had a configuration before reseting network and Router in office... but I preferred to get back to these settings instead of keeping the new one. It's not a solution to forward ports 24 back to 22 cause port 24 will be configured for further traffic, so I need them. Just like to set IP manually and setting pack ports to 22 shouldn't be a problem, due I't already done!